# Why does xargs gvim --remote also open a blank file?

Tags: gvim

If I run `ack foo | xargs gvim`, then gVim opens each named file in a separate buffer in a new instance of gVim. This is good.

However, if I run `ack foo | xargs gvim --remote`, without gVim already running, then gVim opens each named file in a separate buffer, **and opens a blank buffer (`[No file]`)**.

If gVim is already running with a file open, then the blank buffer is *not* opened.

Where does this extra blank buffer come from, and how do I prevent it?

*Note: ack is a grep replacement: http://beyondgrep.com/; if I use `grep -Rl foo .`, the same thing happens.*

Comment: Sounds like it might be your issue: [How can I remove the default empty buffer from vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381039/how-can-i-remove-the-default-empty-buffer-from-vim)